# Using LINQ to get all results where ID in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

i have something like this now, which only searches for 1 LabID

```
List<Expense> lstExpenses = (from l in ctx.Expenses
                             where l.datLab.Lab_ID == labID
                             select l).ToList<Expense>();
```

how do i return all results where Lab_ID is in a dictionary i have:

the followin functions returns a dictionary value:  `report.GetLabChildren(labID, "All");` is in `<short>,<string>` format. i only want to search on the `<short>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to get all items where the Lab_ID is a *range* of values?

Comment: not really a range, it could be 1,10,25, and i want to match just those three, not the values in between

Comment: So the 1,10,25 are in a *dictionary*? Are they keys? Values?

Comment: @SystemDown They're the keys, as per the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Expense> lstExpenses = (from l in ctx.Expenses
                      where report.GetLabChildren(labID, "All").Keys.Contains(i.Lab_ID)
                      select l).ToList<Expense>();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do the filtering in linq to objects:

```
var query = ctx.Expenses.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(expense => dictionary.ContainsKey(espense.Lab_Id));
```

If you want something that can be translated to the database:

```
var ids = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
var query = ctx.Expenses
    .Where(expense => ids.Contains(expense.Lab_Id));
```

Note this will only work if you have less than a few thousand keys in your dictionary, as it is translated to a SQL IN clause.  If you have more than that either upload them to a temporary table and join the two tables, or pull the entire `Expenses` table and use the linq to objects version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking about, but looks like you're looking for `ContainsKey` method:

```
var values = report.GetLabChildren(labID, "All");

List<Expense> lstExpenses = (from l in ctx.Expenses
                             where values.ContainsKey(l.datLab.Lab_ID)
                             select l).ToList<Expense>();
```

I'm not sure, but there is a chance that it won't work with LINQ to Entities. Use following if it happens:

```
List<Expense> lstExpenses = (from l in ctx.Expenses
                             where values.Keys.Contains(l.datLab.Lab_ID)
                             select l).ToList<Expense>();
```